# R, how to replace all the emply elements in a data frame?

Tags: r, replace

I'm working in R, and I would like to replace all the empty elements of my data.frame with a NA value.

So, if I had this data frame as input:

```
         unit        delta
1         aaa           696
2         bbb           388
3                       388
4         ccc             0
5         ddd          1630
6         eee             4
```

then I would like to have this as output:

```
         unit         delta
1         aaa           696
2         bbb           388
3        <NA>           388
4         ccc             0
5         ddd          1630
6         eee             4
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `gsub()`, if your blanks are all consistent it'll get the job done.

Comment: What's the current strcutre of your data? It would help to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Is `unit` a factor or character? Are the blank values, space? zero-length strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regardless of whether it is a character column or a factor column, the `is.na<-` replacement function has a method to handle either.

```
is.na(df) <- df == ""
```

should get the job done fine.  For operating only on the `unit` column, you can do

```
is.na(df$unit) <- df$unit == ""
```

Just to check further, we can assign different classes to the different columns and see what happens.

```
df <- read.csv(text = "unit,delta
bbb,388
,388
ccc,
ddd,1630", colClasses = c("factor", "character"))

df
#   unit delta
# 1  bbb   388
# 2        388
# 3  ccc      
# 4  ddd  1630

is.na(df) <- df == ""
df
#   unit delta
# 1  bbb   388
# 2 <NA>   388
# 3  ccc  <NA>
# 4  ddd  1630

sapply(df, class)
#       unit       delta 
#   "factor" "character"
```

Comment: Might also  worth mentioning that a lot of these problems can be sorted at the input stage by using `na.strings` argument of `read.table` and family

Answer (score 1):

In the Hadleyverse, it'd be something like this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

d <- YOUR DATA

d %>%
  mutate(unit = replace(unit, unit == '', NA))

  unit delta
1  aaa   696
2  bbb   388
3 <NA>   388
4  ccc     0
5  ddd  1630
6  eee     4
```